# Regex to replace special characters at starting and ending but not in middle

Tags: python, regex

I have a input strings like

> ```
> str1 = [( hello world,good morning)]
> str2 = ([ hello world,good morning])
> str3 = [( hello world,(today) is good day])
> ```

and output should be:

> str1 = hello world,good morning
>
> str2 = hello world,good morning
>
> str3 = hello world,(today) is good day

I need a regex to replace special characters at both starting and ending but not in middle of string.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a store that you ask for what you need for, basically, provide your own regex, and someone might help you fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

```
>>> my_string = "[( hello world,good morning)]"
>>> my_string.strip("([ ])") # strips brackets and whitespace from both sides
'hello world,good morning'
```